# ML.NET и преобразование изображений в текст

Tags: c#, ml.net

Может ли `ML.NET` изображения автомобильных номеров преобразовывать в текст ?

Много решений видел на `python`.
Там просто скармливают 10к-1кк примеров и модель уже умеет преобразовывать в текст.

Вот хотелось бы на C# что то такое.
Просто скормить модели 10к-100к подготовленных изображений с учителем A100AA777.JPG.
Она обучится.

А затем передавать ей ГРЗ и получать текст

Comment: Для этого нужно уметь делать "image segmentation" и затем "image classification". Насколько я смог нагуглить, второе оно умеет делать с нуля, а первое нет. Поэтому если только грузить в него готовую модель сегментации (или сегментации и классификации). Если я всё правильно понял.

Comment: @CrazyElf где взять эту модель (сегментации и классификации) для `C#` чтобы я её обучил, т.е. просто скормил ей `10к-100к` таких img (`A100AA777.JPG`,`Т353КВ143.JPG`) и чтобы она поняла что я от неё хочу xD

Comment: Да вот нельзя обучить, я так понял. Надо разбираться, как готовую модель Tensorflow подгрузить, видимо. Сходу не подскажу, я не сильно разбирался в этом всём.